# Insert related multiple records in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL tables and want to insert multiple records instead of creating one by one, get id and insert related records

here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `visit` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip_address` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `visitmeta` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `page_visit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Currently I insert one record on visit, get its id and insert records on visit meta. Is there a way to create a new record into visit and in the same query create visit meta records?

Comment: Can you show us what you have now so we get an idea of the data and exact commands you're trying to run?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to insert records in two tables with a single query, but you can do it in just two queries using MySQL's [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function:

```
INSERT INTO visit
  (ip_address)
VALUES
  ('1.2.3.4')
;

INSERT INTO visitmeta
  (page_visit_id, key, value)
VALUES
  (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'foo', 'bar'),
  (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'baz', 'qux')
;
```

Note also that it's often more convenient/performant to store IP addresses in their raw, four-byte binary form (one can use MySQL's [`INET_ATON()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) and [`INET_NTOA()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) functions to convert to/from such form respectively).

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing. Thanks.