# Inserting into two SQL tables using a value from one

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a simple event registration system using MySQL and PHP. I have four tables:

```
events: event_id, event_name
instance: instance_id, event_id, date
attendee: attendee_id, attendee_name, attendee_email, attendee_tel
registration: reg_id, attendee_id, instance_id
```

To clarify, the instance table contains instances of a given event, ie a specific event on a specific date.

When an attendee registers (via a form), I want to write their details to the `attendee` table, then write the event they have registered for in the `registration` table, along with the relevant `attendee_id`, so that when I query the `registration` table later on, it will show me what event has been registered for and by whom.

However, I'm new to SQL (and databases in general, not to mention PHP as well), so I'm not sure how I can do that given that the `attendee_id` has only just been generated by adding the attendee to the table. I can easily insert a row into the `attendee` table with:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO attendee (attendee_name, attendee_email, attendee_tel) 
      VALUES ( '$fullname', '$email', '$tel' )";
```

With the values obviously being grabbed by `$_POST` from the form. The form also grabs the `instance_id`, incidentally.

So I just need to know how I can insert the relevant information into the `registration` table. Any ideas?

Comment: Presuably, `attendee.attendee_id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key. After you insert your new record into `attendee`, you need to retrieve this generated value for `attendee_id` and then issue a second `INSERT INTO registration` statement. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600527/accessing-last-inserted-row-in-mysql

Comment: Yes, all the _ids are primary A_I keys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert related multiple records in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887246/insert-related-multiple-records-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make these column in tables primary key and auto increment

```
events: event_id

instance: instance_id

attendee: attendee_id

registration: reg_id
```

and you can get the last inserted id when you run query to insert in these table by following code immediate after the insert query

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

use this appropriately

Answer (score 2):

After inserting the data to the 1st table (attendee), use the php function [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id) to get the last auto increment id.

Then run another query to insert the data to the 2nd table (registration).

In such cases, in order to avoid any data mismatch with the two tables, its better to use BEGIN and COMMIT. So that if any MySQL error occurs in between 2nd query, it will automatically role back.

Answer (score 0):

see `mysql_insert_id()`

The mysql_insert_id() function returns the AUTO_INCREMENT ID generated from the previous INSERT operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql_query() for inserting the data into the attendee table, write the mysql_insert_id() in the next line, it will gives you the recently generated attendee_id, store it in a variable and using this variable insert again in the registration table. Something like that:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO attendee (attendee_name, attendee_email, attendee_tel) VALUES ( '$fullname', '$email', '$tel' )";
$rc=mysql_query($q);
$a_id=mysql_insert_id();
```

now insert again in 'registration' table with $a_id;

Comment: Would I need to do this as a `TRANSACTION`?

Comment: I mean, does this have to be done as a transaction as opposed to auto-committing after each query?

Comment: This is a method provided by PHP to extract the last id from a table and it's 100% reliable to use this primary ID as a foreign key in other table. This function should place just after the mysql_query() function. Otherwise it'll return you wrong ID in some cases.